# Can we append a Word document to end of another Word document using Apache POI XWPF?

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I want to append template from one Word document (.docx file) to another Word document. Can we do that using Apache POI XWPF libraries?

Comment: This is the third of three questions on Apache POI from you that are very brief and lack context or code. Questions on which effort has obviously been expended are much more likely to garner interest and answers.